# Need to merge multiple pdf's into a single PDF with Table Of Contents sections

Tags: php, linux, pdf, pdf-generation

Will have 50-100 single PDF's that we'll be generating with a php script. PDF's are generally grouped into groups of 10-20. Each group needs to have it's own Table of Contents or Index, and then there also needs to be a Master Table of Contents or Index at the beginning.

Or if that is too difficult we could get away with a single Table of Contents at the beginning.

What's the best way to go about this?

Will we need to create the Table of Contents and then export that to PDF and append it to the beginning and mash the rest of the files after that? Or is there a better solution?

And what's the best tool for us to merge the pdf's?

Will be running on a Linux server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And what's the best tool for us to merge the pdf's?

On Linux (as well as on Windows), you can install an useful little program, [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). It works well to bind PDF's together. For example:

```
$ pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf in3.pdf in4.pdf in5.pdf in6.pdf cat output out.pdf
```

where `in*.pdf` are the input files and `out.pdf` is the result. In between, @jerik already gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222656) how to deal with the TOC.

Comment: Works with pdftk version 1.45. Example documentation see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40222656/1933185)

Answer (score 12):

With Version 1.45 - December 6, 2012 is `pdftk` able to create bookmarks with [update_info](https://www.pdflabs.com/blog/export-and-import-pdf-bookmarks/), which could be used as toc.

Its done in 3 Steps:

#### Precondition for my example

3 PDF files. Single page.

```
page1.pdf
page2.pdf
page3.pdf
```

#### 1. Create the bookmark information

```
# build the bookmark out of an example file
pdftk page1.pdf dump_data output meta.txt
# Edit meta.txt as you need
```

Heres an example that worked for me, meta.txt:

```
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Creator
InfoValue: PDFTK
NumberOfPages: 3
PageMediaBegin
PageMediaNumber: 1
PageMediaRotation: 0
PageMediaRect: 0 0 595.32 841.92
PageMediaDimensions: 595.32 841.92
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Page 1
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 1
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Page 2
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 2
BookmarkBegin
BookmarkTitle: Page 3
BookmarkLevel: 1
BookmarkPageNumber: 3
```

#### 2. Create an temporary merged pdf file

```
pdftk page* cat output temp.pdf
```

#### 3. Add the bookmarks to the pdf

```
pdftk temp.pdf update_info meta.txt output final.pdf
```

When you open the final.pdf in acrobat reader you see the bookmarks on the left side. 
[image]

Comment: Still this needs manually searching and entering page numbers. Is there any method where pdfs are merged and bookmarks are automatically created at the pages where the pdfs got merged?

Comment: Not tested, but theoretically all steps could be automated through a script. Then you do not have to do anything manually. Besides writing the script once.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the process of generating table of contents for PDF files, I've successfully generated LaTeX code from php and then used latex2pdf to generate the PDF file.

Maybe this could be an alternative, in your case.

To merge PDFs, I agree with Federico that pdftk is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gs` like this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=combined.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

[PDF SAM](https://www.chip.de/downloads/PDFsam-Basic_29495960.html) will make it:

[image: Correct named and ordered pdf files, regard settings: bookmarks are crucial.]

As shown in the image the open source tool can create a bookmark for each file, which provides a correct table of contents:

[image: Result in Edge with proper table of contents]