# Add in the LaTeX TOC an included PDF

Tags: latex, tex

In my document I include a PDF using

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{./mypdf.pdf}
```

The problem I'm having is how to add a TOC entry for this pdf.

It supposed to be an appendix. I tried adding a new section in the appendix but of course the section name can't be printed on the same page than the included pdf, so the resulting TOC line directs to a wrong page.

If I use `\addcontentsline` I loose the numbering and the page is wrong too because the included pdf actually starts at the next page...

I'm a bit lost here so I would really appreciate if someone knows how to do this.

Note: the pdf I try to include was not generated from LaTex.

Comment: Haven't we had this question before?

Comment: I can't find an exact duplicate. The following link sounds really close, but the original poster accepted an answer that doesn't answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418871/need-to-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-a-single-pdf-with-table-of-contents-sections

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the documentation of [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfpages.html) (page 6) it looks like there is an experimental tag called `addtotoc`. I think you'd use it like:

```
\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={<page number>, section, 1, <heading>, <label>}]
```

Where `<page number>` is the desired page number *of the included PDF* (edit) **to link to**, `<heading>` is the title in the TOC, and `<label>` is how you may `\ref` to the section.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly the option I was looking for... I feel stupid not having looked inside the doc the pdfpages package...


EDIT: <page number> is the number of the page that should be used as the reference in the TOC (so it's 1 most of the time)

Comment: Thanks for following up, I altered the answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Hi Geoff and @Heyyou'reQt - see also [Include pdf and reference pages • Page Layout • LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=7528): "_... puts an entry in the toc for **page 4 of the included pdf**..._" Cheers!

Comment: Note that `heading` which will appear in TOC can include spaces, while `label` cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
\section[text for toc]{text for document}
```

in your case

```
\section[text for toc]{}
```

to suppress the output in the document.

Comment: That adds a line in the TOC  with the right label but it still points to the wrong page, and even if the label isn't printed in the document, the appendix number still is ^^
That's why it still points to the wrong page.

Isn't there a way to force the page number on which a toc label points?

Comment: Do you have a .toc file? You could try to edit that before the final compilation ..