# Make one PDF file of Python documentation

Tags: python, pdf-generation, python-sphinx

The Python official site offers PDF documentation downloads, but they are separated by chapters. I downloaded the source code and built the PDF documentation, which were separate PDFs also.

How can I **build one PDF file from the Makefile in the source code**? I think that would be more convenient to read.

If concatenating the separate PDFs won't leaves out the table of contents (bookmarks), it would be acceptable too. I tried `convert` from Imagemagick, `pdftk` and `pdfunite` from `poppler-utils`, they all lose the bookmarks after concatenation.

Comment: I find the source documents are treated as separate **document**, and thus separated Latex files and PDFs are generated. Maybe not possible to generate one PDF with Sphinx.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you already have PDFs, there is no need to re-create them. Instead, use something like [PDF Split & Merge](http://pdfmerge.sourceforge.net/) or [PDFArchitect](http://www.pdfarchitect.org/).

--- edit ---

Since the above mentioned solutions work only partially, I googled a bit and found [sejda](http://www.sejda.org/). You can download latest version [here](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/releases).

```
sejda-console merge -f PDFfile_1.pdf PDFfile_2.pdf -o PDFoutput.pdf
```

I tried it and it works as expected.

Try `sejda-console -h merge` for other options (i.e. specify dir with PDFs instead single files, etc.)

-- edit2 --

It seems `sejda-console` is not freely available anymore, only as commercial `sejda-console-pro`

But the current free version of [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org/) (v.4.2.12) allows for the same bookmarking options.

Both appear to have the same developer.

Comment: I tried, but it only allows you to specify one bookmark entry for each input PDF, which is insufficient for convenient browsing.

Comment: You are right, PDF split and merge only create one bookmark for each input PDF. I googled a bit and I think I found the solution, so I edited my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: I also posted answer to a similar question at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969479 .

Comment: To get a per-file bookmark added to the merged PDF, I had to do this:
`sejda-console merge -b one_entry_each_doc -o merged.pdf --overwrite -f *.pdf`
May also want '-t file_names' option to add a TOC page at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install poppler
pdfunite *.pdf all.pdf
```