# wkhtmltopdf: Is it possible to merge PDF files?

Tags: php, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, qtwebkit

Using this library [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), is it possible to merge 2 pdf files. I need to generate a report and merge the report with some attached documents.

Generation of report is done, converting from HTML to PDF. But I need to merge the resulting PDF with some other PDFs

Comment: You can use [`PDFtk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) which has all kinds of options for merging PDFs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`wkhtmltopdf` doesn't provide support for merging PDF's. You can accomplish this using `GhostScript`. It's a pretty powerful tool and frequently used by Linux users.

You can use the following command:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in1.pdf in2.pdf
```

You can try these links for further reading:

- [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Readme.htm)
- [Merge PDF's using Ghostscript (Windows)](http://www.hyperbytez.com/2011/5/23/pdf-merge-using-ghostscript.aspx)

In case you want it for Linux refer

- [Merge PDF's using Ghostscript (Linux)](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8229-putting-together-pdf-files)

**EDIT:** As stated by @nenotelp there are other tools available as well. The part that @nentelp mentioned is regarding the handling of bookmarks which is better with `iText` or `iTextSharp`. If this is your requirement you can certainly opt for other tools.

P.S. - Google Ghostscript. You will find tons of references.

Comment: This is true, BUT I would highly recommend iText or iTextSharp for the merge - wkhtmltopdf bookmarks are not your dads bookmarks, they don't play well with GhostScript. They don't play well with pdftk either. I know that you are about tho say something like "Ghostscript with pdfmark can easily deal with that" - it should, but it won't :P.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108884/694325 with an awesome answer regarding this topic. When I tested it, it did not work with wkhtmltopdf bookmarks. Also the TOC get screwed, but there's nothing you can do about that - wkhtmltopdf TOC anchors are not unique ARGFHH! I have complained about this into the bug system but Antialize is too busy and nobody else has stepped up yet because of the QT mess.

Comment: the problem with gs is sometimes thrown undefinedfilename error,

Answer (score 4):

You can combine multiple html files to one output pdf file with this library.
For e.g if u have:

```
my-html-file-nr-1.html
my-html-file-nr-2.html
....
my-html-file-nr-n.html
```

You can simply:

```
wkhtmltopdf my-html-file-nr-* output.pdf
```

Comment: He specifically asked about merging two PDFs.

Comment: if i create 1 pdf form 2 html-s do you know if this will restart the page count? so on the footer html1 shows the page count, then does the html2 restart the page count?