# Gnuplot / Ghostscript create a table of content

Tags: gnuplot, ghostscript

I'm currently developping a java application that processes information and that info has to be saved as graphs in a pdf file. I got like 60 graphs as output, all with a different title.

What is an easy way to make a table of content from all the graphs based on their title?
Is there a command that can do this? Or do I have to use pdfmarks?

I can't find anything about this on the internet because if I use the words table of content I just get the table of content of gnuplot/ghostscript itself...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gnuplot can't create bookmarks in pdf files. See e.g [Merge PDF's with PDFTK with Bookmarks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969479/merge-pdfs-with-pdftk-with-bookmarks) to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the PDF using Latex and then use the epslatex terminal in gnuplot to generate the figures. You can write a script which generates the Latex document.

The gnuplot script:

```
set term epslatex color size 3,2 font 6
set output "figure1.eps"
#
set title 'Title of figure1'
#
plot sin(x)
#
exit
```

This generates an EPS file named figure1.eps and a Latex file named figure1.tex which embeds the EPS.

The the following Latex can in turn embed figure1.tex into a document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\include{figure1}
\caption[Description of figure1 as it appears on the list of
figures]{Caption of figure1.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Using the `\listoffigures` command a list of figures will be generated. You might need to run Latex a couple of times before the table appears. Then use `dvipdf` to export to PDF. The result should look like this:

[image]