# Concatenate pdf and add table of contents

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have several pdf files (say chapters of a book) and I want to concatenate them and add a table of contents to the resulting pdf.

No original pdf file has a table of contents. Simple numbers as the table of contents is more than fine.

I know that I can concatenate the pdf files using tools such as pdftk. Another possibility would be to use LaTeX to create table of contents and include each pdf file.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969479/merge-pdfs-with-pdftk-with-bookmarks or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418871/need-to-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-a-single-pdf-with-table-of-contents-sections work for you?

Comment: This one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222656